# Android setX() and setY()

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android and I have a weird behavior in the functions above. My device resolution is `480x800`.

Here is xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="lpoo2016.risk.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonArgentina"
        android:layout_width="10pt"
        android:layout_height="10pt"
        android:background="@drawable/red_marker"
        android:text="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my code:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonArgentina);
float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
button.setY(480/2/scale);
button.setX(800/2);
```

From my understanding, `setX()` and `setY()` arguments are pixels. On setY() I have to divide by density (scale) so my button appears in the middle of Y axis, however on setX() I can't divide it by scale so that my button appears in the middle of X axis. So I don't think I'm passing pixels to setX(), but if I divide by scale it goes a bit to the left and my button is not centered as i want it to be...

**Note:** My purpose is not to center the button, this is just a test. I need to put several buttons on specific parts of images.

Thanks for your attention and sorry for my English :)

Comment: x and y are the coordinates for the top-left corner of your element, I assume you took that into consideration?

Comment: also, if y is 480, your device is portrait, but there are also other elements on the screen that take some space, like the status bar.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, im setting it as landscape via //activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"//. So, in the Xaxis I have the 800. if i use button.setX(400) works fine but if i use setX(400/scale=267) it goes a bit to the left (i said up but meant left, sorry!). I dont have any bars interfering in the Xaxis, i only have an image as background...

Comment: X and y are coordinates of TopLeft end of Button